# Are memory leaks permanent?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

When one uses malloc in a program and does not free the memory, is it lost on the computer that ran the program after the program has run and terminated?

Comment: Not on a modern OS. This is quite a broad question I'm afraid.

Comment: All resources acquired by process will be released by modern OS after process has been terminated. Note it will not be a graceful release (your code can't process that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends upon the operating system (more precisely, of your particular C implementation, which implicitly contains your OS). You need to read more about OSes, e.g. the [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) textbook (freely downloadable).

On modern OSes like Linux, Unix (including MacOSX, Android, etc...), Windows, etc... each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). When the process terminates, its entire virtual address space disappears (including any "memory leaks").

In practice, `malloc` and `free` are built above operating system primitives managing the virtual address space (on Linux, these primitives are [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & `munmap` and perhaps the old [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)) and [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging). Notice that `free` usually don't release memory to the OS (e.g. with  `munmap`) but more often mark the freed memory zone as reusable by future `malloc`-s.

However, avoiding [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) is a good discipline (and is essential for long-lived processes like servers). Then, tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [address sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) could help in detecting them.

A good [book](http://gchandbook.org/) on [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) gives you the concept and terminology related to [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management). Read also about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). Think of [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference), [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference), etc....

<sup>(on old systems like MS-DOS, this might have not been the case, but details matter a lot; on some embedded systems, too)</sup>